# why shadowRoot.querySelector returns null?

Tags: html, dom

I need to access element inside the #shadow-root (open).
I used the 'Copy JS Path' in Chrome browser to get code as following.
but it returned null.
if I just take the first shadowRoot, it looked OK.
but the next level returned null.
How can I fix it?
thanks in advance!

```js
document.querySelector('body > sn-workspace-layout > sn-workspace-main > sn-workspace-primary-content > sn-ux-content-option:nth-child(3) > sn-workspace-list-module').shadowRoot
```

```js
document.querySelector('body > sn-workspace-layout > sn-workspace-main > sn-workspace-primary-content > sn-ux-content-option:nth-child(3) > sn-workspace-list-module').shadowRoot.querySelector('div > div.list-wrapper > now-record-list-connected').shadowRoot.querySelector('div > now-record-list').shadowRoot.querySelector('div > div.sn-list-grid-container > div > now-table').shadowRoot.querySelector('#gridcontainer > div > table')
```

Comment: Can you share the website link for testing?

Comment: It works fine if I run it in the console. but it just failed if I have this run in my userscript such as ViolentMonkey